# Is there any other way to write this query?( I am getting "Subquery returned more than 1 value error"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am creating a function where I have to pass multiple Id's (suppose A.id) (int) as comma separated like (2,3) values and the result will be the values(int) related to those ID's. suppose if I passed (2,3) the result should be like (8,9,7,5).

```
declare @roleid varchar(max)  
set @roleid=(select mr.Id from M_Organization mo
join m_role mr on mr.Id=mo.RoleId 
cross apply STRING_SPLIT ('3,4', ',') cs WHERE mo.Id IN (cs.value)
)
select @roleid
```

It Shows Following Error:

> Sub query returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   sub query follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the sub query is used
>   as an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
declare @roleid varchar(max)  
set @roleid=(select top 1 mr.Id from M_Organization mo
join m_role mr on mr.Id=mo.RoleId 
cross apply STRING_SPLIT ('3,4', ',') cs WHERE mo.Id IN (cs.value)
)
select @roleid
```

Comment: Yeah Got it. Thank You

Comment: @john897 I don't think this code is right.  Is your intent to get 1st ID from m_role table?  If that's the case, sure - you are good.  But the reason you are getting the `subquery returned more than 1 value` is because there is more than one match.  You need to tighten up your logic.

Comment: @AngryHacker Yes this is syntactical correct but for correct output logically I also think they need to change their logic either in schema as they store data or at the time of selection/update.

Comment: @SurajKumar Yes, I am not questioning your code, but john897's code logic.

Comment: @AngryHacker the actual logic is suppose we have program Id's and when we passed those id's I have to get the subprogram id's under all those programs in comma seperated values...The above query with top clause returns the exact values..Was my query correct Logically??...The whole function is different but this is the main partof the query

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TOP 1 in the query. Bacause your assigning value to the variable and it takes only one return value from the query.

```
declare @roleid varchar(max)  
set @roleid=(select TOP 1 mr.Id from M_Organization mo
join m_role mr on mr.Id=mo.RoleId 
cross apply STRING_SPLIT ('3,4', ',') cs WHERE mo.Id IN (cs.value)
)
select @roleid
```